# Day of the week for extended forecast

Tags: c#, xslt-1.0

The purpose of this is to have the first day of the forecast to be current day of the week, and for the rest follow. 0 is obviously sunday and 6 is saturday. I am trying to figure out if this will work properly or if there is a better way. The c# code below shows how I figured its the easiest way to do it, but obviously my math goes over 6 so it doesnt show the days towards the end. To be very clear I just need the days of the week to be in order from the current day so I can apply to the xsl code that I also show an example of. Each position in the xsl is considered a day. If you can help me with the math part i think this will work.

```
`               DayOfWeek day1 = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
                    DayOfWeek day2 = day1 + 1;
                    DayOfWeek day3 = day2 + 1;
                    DayOfWeek day4 = day3 + 1;
                    DayOfWeek day5 = day4 + 1;
                    DayOfWeek day6 = day5 + 1;
                    DayOfWeek day7 = day6 + 1;
                    switch (day1)
                    {
                        default:
                        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:                      
                            break;
                        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                            break;
                        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                            break;
                        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                            break;
                        case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                            break;
                        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                            break;
                        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                            break;

                    }
                     xFore.Root.Add(new XElement("day", day1),
                         new XElement("day2", day2),
                         new XElement("day3", day3),
                         new XElement("day4", day4),
                         new XElement("day5", day5),
                         new XElement("day6", day6),
                         new XElement("day7", day7));`



`                     <xsl:if test ="position()=1">Today</xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test ="position()=2">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//day2"/>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test ="position()=3">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//day3"/>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test ="position()=4">
                      <xsl:value-of select="//day4"/>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test ="position()=5">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//day5"/>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test ="position()=6">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//day6"/>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test ="position()=7">
                        <xsl:value-of select="//day7"/>
                      </xsl:if>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the modulus operator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) to prevent from going over 6:

```
DayOfWeek day1 = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
DayOfWeek day2 = (DayOfWeek)((byte)(day1 + 1) % 7);
DayOfWeek day3 = (DayOfWeek)((byte)(day2 + 1) % 7);
DayOfWeek day4 = (DayOfWeek)((byte)(day3 + 1) % 7);
DayOfWeek day5 = (DayOfWeek)((byte)(day4 + 1) % 7);
DayOfWeek day6 = (DayOfWeek)((byte)(day5 + 1) % 7);
DayOfWeek day7 = (DayOfWeek)((byte)(day6 + 1) % 7);

// Rest of code omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try to resolve your issue. If I'm correct you just need to implement a mod operation so that no one number is above 6?

Example:

```
DayOfWeek[] Days = new DayOfWeek[7];

DayOfWeek[0] = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
For(Int i=1;i < 7;i++)
  DayOfWeek[i] = (DayOfWeek)(((byte)DayOfWeek[i-1]+1) % 7);

XElement[] XmlDays = new XElement[7];
For(Int i=0;i < 7;i++)
  XmlDays[i] = new XElement("day" + i.ToString(), DayOfWeek[i]);

xFore.Root.Add(XmlDays);
```